# Is a callback also known as a higher-order function?

Tags: javascript, callback, terminology, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to understand **callback** and **higher-order** functions but there's a description from a blog post, [Understand JavaScript Callback Functions and Use Them](https://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/), that confuses me, the implication being that they are one and the same:

> A callback function, also known as a higher-order function,...

It was repeated verbatim on a Quora answer to the question asking about [What is a simple explanation of higher order functions and callbacks in JavaScript?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-simple-explanation-of-higher-order-functions-and-callbacks-in-JavaScript).

It doesn't make sense to me. From what I understand, a **higher-order** function *takes in or returns other functions* and a **callback** function *is the function being passed/taken in*, so how can it be both at the same time? Is there something that I'm not understanding about that description?

Comment: I would go with the definition from Wikipedia - that article seems to have used the term incorrectly.

Comment: Many people get these concepts confused, since they're so closely related.

Comment: If you're having trouble with this concept please look into closures. It'll help to understand the difference a lot easier. This might help in that endeavor: https://medium.com/@zfrisch/destroying-buildings-a-simple-guide-to-javascript-closures-ef9fc326c73d

Comment: Yes, [people in the comments section of the article](https://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/#comment-307225) noted the wrong terminology too

Comment: @zfrisch No, how closures work is not relevant to define the terms "callback" and "higher-order function".

Comment: @Bergi the process of understanding what a closure is imo is helpful because returning a function from a function etc becomes much easier to conceptualize, but hey, w/e.

Comment: @zfrisch looking at closures was next on my list :)

Comment: @Bergi I didn't realize other people were calling that out in the comments. but now it appears that I can't even access the article...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

> A callback function is a function passed into another function as an
>   argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete
>   some kind of routine or action.

[Return a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function#Example_Return_a_function)

> A function that returns a function called Higher-Order Function

A callback function is *not* a Higher-Order Function, *unless* it is a function that returns a function.

**Simple callback:**

```js
function toto(callback){
  /** some routine or action before */
  callback();
}

function foo(){
  console.log("I'm a simple callback");
}

toto(foo);
```

**Simple Higher-Order Function**

```js
function toto(){
  console.log("I'm a simple Higher-Order Function")
  return function(){
     console.log("I'm the return function");
  }
}

//first log
const func = toto();
//second log
func();
```

**Callback that is also a Higher-Order Function:**

```js
function toto(callback){
  /** some routine or action before */
  const func = callback();
  func();
}

function foo(){
  console.log("I'm a callback and Higher-Order function");
  
  return function(){
    console.log("Do something...");
  };
}

toto(foo);
```

Comment: thank you for that example! Absolutely clarifies the muddy water in explaining how a callback may be a higher-order function, but they're not necessarily one and the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, a callback is not necessarily a Higher Order Function. They can be though. You could have a callback that accepts another function as an argument.

Callbacks are *given* to Higher Order Functions, which may be what's leading to the confusion. A function accepting another function as an argument is one of the criteria that causes it to be classified as Higher Order.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, higher order function is a function that takes another function and uses it to abstract some behaviour, e.g. this c# extension method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, object> selector)
    {
        return items.Select(x => new { o = selector(x), item = x })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.o)
                    .Select(x=> x.item);
    }
```

it takes a function determining, which property take into account while sorting collection.
Sample usage:

```
    var orderedByA = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
          .Select(x=> new Item{
            A = x,
            B = 100 - x
          })
          .OrderByProperty(x => x.A);
```

Callbacks on the other hand can be used to continue application flow when some async or long action is necessary, e.g.

```
void FirstAsync(){
    Task.Run(()=>{
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("First executed");
    });
}

void Second()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Second executed");
}

void FirstV2(Action callback)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("First executed");
        callback?.Invoke();
    });
}

void Main()
{
    FirstAsync();
    Second();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    FirstV2(Second);
}
```

Output of program above will be like:

```
Second executed
First executed
First executed
Second executed
```